# Fetching and submitting data to database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

my code fetches entries from the database and prints them into separate forms so that i could accept or deny each of them using buttons of different actions. Whenever i perform an action on one of the forms, it would not do the operation on the same form but instead it moves by order starting from the first entry in the database.

[image]

In the picture above, if i accepted the second form, it would perform the function on the first form.

Code:

```
<?php
} else if ($usertype == 1) { 
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
$server = "";
$user = "";
$pass = "r=~";
$db = "";
$db3 = "aukwizcq_professors";
$user1 = $_SESSION['username'];
$mysqli  = new Mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db) or mysqli_error($mysqli);
$mysqli5  = new Mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db3) or  mysqli_error($mysqli);
$name= $mysqli5->query("SELECT name FROM professor WHERE username= '$user1'")->fetch_object()->name;   //taking name from list of professors that are equal to the userid logged in (if hes a professor, it will show, if not 0)
$overrides = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Overrides WHERE professor= '$name' AND status ='1'"); 
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($overrides);



echo "&nbsp;Pending Overrides: " . $num_rows; 
?>
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($overrides)) { ?>
    <fieldset>
                    <form method="post" action="dbheads.php" name="HF" id="HF" autocomplete="off">

     <?php 
         echo "First Name:&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['name'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Mid. Name:&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['mname'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Fam. Name:&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['fname'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Student ID:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $row['sid'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Scolarship:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['sc'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Phone No:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['phone'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['email'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Subject:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['subject'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Section:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['section'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Semester:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['semester'] . "<br />";
                  echo "<br />Professor:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['professor'] . "<br />";  

                  $id = $row['id'];
                  echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>";
             $name = $row['name'];
             echo "<input type='hidden' name='name' value='$name'>";
         $mname = $row['mname'];
         echo "<input type='hidden' name='mname' value='$mname'>";
         $fname = $row['fname'];
         echo "<input type='hidden' name='fname' value='$fname'>";
         $sid = $row['sid'];
         echo "<input type='hidden' name='sid' value='$sid'>";
         $sc = $row['sc'];
         echo "<input type='hidden' name='sc' value='$sc'>";
         $phone = $row['phone'];
         echo "<input type='hidden' name='phone' value='$phone'>";
         $email = $row['email'];                
          echo "<input type='hidden' name='email' value='$email'>";
         $subject = $row['subject'];
                  echo "<input type='hidden' name='subject' value='$subject'>";
         $section = $row['section'];
                  echo "<input type='hidden' name='section' value='$section'>";
         $semester = $row['semester'];
                  echo "<input type='hidden' name='semester' value='$semester'>";
         //$professor = $row['professor'];
                 // echo "<input type='hidden' name='professor' value='$professor'>";



         ?>
<br />
<div>
<label for="comments" accesskey="c">Notes & Comments:</label><br />
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
<br>
</div>
<br>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm(action)
    {
        document.getElementById('HF').action = action;
        document.getElementById('HF').submit();
    }
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="submitForm('dbheads.php')" value="Accept" />
<input type="button" onclick="submitForm('dbheads2.php')" value="Deny" />   </form>

    </fieldset>
    <br>
<?php    
}

 ?>
```

dbheads.php

```
<?php 
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';
sec_session_start();
?>
<html>

<?php
$mysql_host     = "localhost";
$mysql_username = "";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "";
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
  if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
            <p>Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($user); ?>!</p>
            <?php 
$mysqli  = new Mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database) or die(mysqli_error());
$status = 2;
$id = $_POST['id'];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE Overrides SET status=? WHERE id='$id'");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $status);
$stmt->execute();
print 'Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error;
 echo htmlentities(accepted);
 ?>
         <?php else : ?>
            <p>
                <span class="error">You are not authorized to access this page.</span> Please <a href="index.php">login</a>.
            </p>
        <?php endif; ?>

</html>
```

Any help for fixing please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you sending form by ID and you have same id (it is invalid) for all forms.

if you will make unique id for form like this:

```
<form method="post" name="HF" id="HF_<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" autocomplete="off">
```

And after you change your JavaScript like this:

```
document.getElementById('HF_<?php echo $row['id'] ?>').action = action;
document.getElementById('HF_<?php echo $row['id'] ?>').submit();
```

It will be working

If i can little improve your code i have this suggestions for you:

If you will use  you don't need more your JavaScript and you can test what button was submitted in PHP (best practice). Example:

```
<form method="post" name="HF" id="HF_<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="hidden" name="HF[id]" />
        <input type="hidden" name="HF[name]" />
        <input type="hidden" name="HF[mname]" />
        <input type="hidden" name="HF[fname]" />
        <input type="hidden" name="HF[sid]" />
        <button type="submit" value="1" name="HF[accept]">Accept</button>
        <button type="submit" value="1" name="HF[reset]">Reset</button>
    </form>
```

And PHP testing

```
if(isset($_POST['HF'])){
     if($_POST['HF']['accept']){
         // do accept
     }
     elseif($_POST['HF']['reset']){
         // do reset
     }
 }
```

If you see i don't need set separate actions per each action and i have form prefix and it means i can send multiple forms on this url but only one will be processed

Comment: hello lukas, i have tested your first fix, changed the javascript and id of the form but it is still submitting the forms in order instead of the one i select.

Answer (score 0):

There are one thing in my mind:
You are using JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm(action)
    {
        document.getElementById('HF').action = action;
        document.getElementById('HF').submit();
    }
</script>
```

to submit your form on the basis of form ID. But you have provided same ID for all forms generated in the loop. And JS is performing on first ID Occurrence.